# CallKit Call Directory Extension don't identify numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, callkit

I think to have correctly set up the CallKit Extension to provide custom identification for the telephone numbers.

Here my AppDelegate snippet to test if the extension is correctly set up

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  
  [[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.******.CallerID"
                                                completionHandler:^(CXCallDirectoryEnabledStatus enabledStatus, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier - Status: %ld - Error: %@", (long)enabledStatus, error);
  }];
  
  [[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.******.CallerID"
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"reloadExtensionWithIdentifier - Error: %@", error);
  }];
}
```

And the relative logs

```
getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier - Status: 2 - Error: (null)
reloadExtensionWithIdentifier - Error: (null)
```

And my extension code

```
@interface CallDirectoryHandler () <CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate>
@end

@implementation CallDirectoryHandler

- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
  context.delegate = self;
  
  if (context.isIncremental) {
    [context removeAllIdentificationEntries];
  }
  
  [self addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:context];
  
  [context completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}

- (void)addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
  CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber newNumber = 4155499275;
  [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:newNumber
                                                         label:@"My best friend"];
}
```

And the result, nothin appear on the screen

[image]

What I am doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: You forgot the leading 1 for the us country code

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, solved. So I have to add the prefix every time?

Comment: Yes, phone numbers need to. Be in e.164 format.